# Google APi Bad Request

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-pay

i try to implement Passes service of Google Api in our website but we always have error 400 problem

we follow this documentation 
[Giftcardclass: insert](https://developers.google.com/pay/passes/reference/v1/giftcardclass/insert)

i use postman for test

> POST https://www.googleapis.com/walletobjects/v1/giftCardClass

Request body

```
{  
   "kind":"walletobjects#loyaltyObject",
   "id":"test2.test",
   "classId":"test.test",
   "version":12,
   "state":"active",
   "issuername":"dsadasdasdas",
   "barcode":{  
      "kind":"walletobjects#barcode",
      "type":"ean13",
      "value":"aaaa",
      "alternateText":"aaaa"
   }
}
```

jSon response

```
{    "error": {
       "errors": [
           {
               "domain": "global",
               "reason": "invalidArgument",
               "message": "Bad Request"
          }
      ],
      "code": 400,
      "message": "Bad Request"    } 
}
```

from the documentation seems that only id,issuerstate and reviewStatus are required.

Comment: invalidArgument  have you gone though your arguments to ensure that you are setting the corect datatype?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your ids are formatted wrongly, it should be issuer_id.unique_id. See https://developers.google.com/pay/passes/rest/v1/giftcardclass#GiftCardClass.FIELDS.id for reference.